# Threads in Java | wait(), notify() and notifyAll()

Tags: java, java-threads

I have an interface as below(assume it's a Java Interface and methods with void return types)

```
interface FileAccessOperations{
    fun requestReadAccess()
    fun releaseReadAccess()
    fun requestWriteAccess()
    fun releaseWriteAccess()
}
```

Now I have to implement these methods where I need to manage single file's read/write permission between large number of threads.

I have implemented as below.

```
public class FileOperationsImpl implements FileAccessOperations {

    /* When count is
     * (equals 0) -> File is free, no thread is accessing it (Write and read request is possible)
     * (greater than 0) -> File is being read by #count of threads.(Reads are still possible. No write)
     * (lesser than 0) -> File is in write mode.(Write/Read is not possible)
     *
     * So basically, the file can read by multiple threads at a time.
     * But only one thread can write at a given time.
     */
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    synchronized public void requestReadAccess() {
        while(count < 0){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public void releaseReadAccess() {
        if(count > 0){
            count--;
        }
        if(count == 0){
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public void requestWriteAccess() {
        while(count != 0){
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        count--;
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public void releaseWriteAccess() {
        count = 0;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

Did I do it right?

Comment: I hope youre doing this for eductional purposes only, since there are multiple R-W-Locks implemented in the Core Java Lib

Comment: @codeflush.dev yes this is truely for my practice on Java Thread concepts.

Comment: First of all, every invocation to `wait()` should be wrapped in a while loop. See that JavaDoc for more information. Second: In the method `requestWriteAccess`, if the count is `!= 0` you wait for a `notify`. But after your thread has been woken up, you don't set to count to `-1`

Comment: Yes, I understood the bug. I should decrement the count that successful if block.

Comment: @codeflush.dev And Now I got the wait part. If we do not keep it loop part, the value may be updated after notify(). is it looking good?

Answer (score 1):

I see several issues with your implementation:

1. `releaseReadAccess` does not check if any read access is actually held, and thus can acquire write access (make `count` go negative).
2. `releaseWriteAccess` has a similar problem, it can increase count beyond 0, creating false read lock.
3. If `requestWriteAccess` is called while any lock exists, it will block until lock is released, but then do nothing.
   Since this function does not return any value, the calling thread will never know it didn't actually get the lock.
4. Similar issue with `requestReadAccess` - it will wait until it can grant the lock, but won't increment `count`, so no lock will be granted.

Generally speaking, it is a better design practice to have `request` functions return `true` or `false` to indicate weather lock was successfully obtained, even if they block, just in case there are some error conditions.

Comment: I agree with the edge cases you pointed out and made the respective changes. Is that looking good?

Comment: The most important thing I missed is ```wait()``` inside the loop as @codeflush.dev mentioned.

Comment: @Sundeep1501 nothing else I can see, but the best way to make sure is to create a test program.